# How to locate elements in iOS UI test for flutter fastlane screnshots

Tags: xcode, flutter, fastlane

I want to be able to tap on one of the buttons in the bottom nav bar to navigate to each tab of my app in order to take screenshots. I set it all up according to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/ and the screenshotting works successfully. The issue is I cannot figure out how to address the button. I assumed I would be able to just do something like this:

```
print(app.navigationBars)
```

But this returns the inscrutable:

```
<XCUIElementQuery: 0x600003b46b20>
```

I then thought to look at the hierarchical view of the app in XCode (as per [How do I inspect the view hierarchy in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios)), but for Flutter apps it just shows up with a bunch of black boxes with unhelpful names.

In general, how do I figure out how to address buttons as part of these UI tests for taking screenshots? Some are intuitive, like `app.buttons["Search"]`, but others don't work quite so easily, e.g. `app.navigationBars["Revision"]`.

Other resources I've read include the following, but they weren't super useful:

- [How to print all the staticTexts in XCUITest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847368/how-to-print-all-the-statictexts-in-xcuitest)
- [How to get index of XCUIElement in XCUIElementQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164956/how-to-get-index-of-xcuielement-in-xcuielementquery)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pavlo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9248201/pavlo-ostasha) answer is what I ended up going with. I wanted to respond to this with a more complete guide explaining what to do.

First, add these `dev_dependencies` to `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
```

Then make a file called `test_driver/integration_driver.dart` like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    await integrationDriver(
      onScreenshot: (String screenshotName, List<int> screenshotBytes) async {
        final File image = await File('screenshots/$screenshotName.png')
            .create(recursive: true);
        image.writeAsBytesSync(screenshotBytes);
        return true;
      },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error occured taking screenshot: $e');
  }
}
```

Then make a file called something like `integration_test/screenshot_test.dart`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import 'package:auslan_dictionary/common.dart';
import 'package:auslan_dictionary/flashcards_landing_page.dart';
import 'package:auslan_dictionary/globals.dart';
import 'package:auslan_dictionary/main.dart';
import 'package:auslan_dictionary/word_list_logic.dart';

// Note, sometimes the test will crash at the end, but the screenshots do
// actually still get taken.

Future<void> takeScreenshot(
    WidgetTester tester,
    IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding,
    ScreenshotNameInfo screenshotNameInfo,
    String name) async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  }
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  await binding.takeScreenshot(
      "${screenshotNameInfo.platformName}/en-AU/${screenshotNameInfo.deviceName}-${screenshotNameInfo.physicalScreenSize}-${screenshotNameInfo.getAndIncrementCounter()}-$name");
}

class ScreenshotNameInfo {
  String platformName;
  String deviceName;
  String physicalScreenSize;
  int counter = 1;

  ScreenshotNameInfo(
      {required this.platformName,
      required this.deviceName,
      required this.physicalScreenSize});

  int getAndIncrementCounter() {
    int out = counter;
    counter += 1;
    return out;
  }

  static Future<ScreenshotNameInfo> buildScreenshotNameInfo() async {
    Size size = window.physicalSize;
    String physicalScreenSize = "${size.width.toInt()}x${size.height.toInt()}";

    DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

    String platformName;
    String deviceName;
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platformName = "android";
      AndroidDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      deviceName = info.product;
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      platformName = "ios";
      IosDeviceInfo info = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      deviceName = info.name;
    } else {
      throw "Unsupported platform";
    }

    return ScreenshotNameInfo(
        platformName: platformName,
        deviceName: deviceName,
        physicalScreenSize: physicalScreenSize);
  }
}

void main() async {
  final IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding =
      IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding();
  binding.framePolicy = LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBindingFramePolicy.fullyLive;
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  testWidgets("takeScreenshots", (WidgetTester tester) async {

    // Just examples of taking screenshots.
    await takeScreenshot(tester, binding, screenshotNameInfo, "search");

    final Finder searchField = find.byKey(ValueKey("searchPage.searchForm"));
    await tester.tap(searchField);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.enterText(searchField, "hey");
    await takeScreenshot(tester, binding, screenshotNameInfo, "searchWithText");
  });
}
```

You can then invoke it like this:

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_driver.dart --target=integration_test/screenshot_test.dart -d 'iPhone 13 Pro Max'
```

Make sure to first make the appropriate directories, like this:

```sh
mkdir -p screenshots/ios/en-AU
mkdir -p screenshots/android/en-AU
```

There is currently an issue with Flutter / its testing deps that as of 2.10.4 means you have to alter the testing package: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91668. In short, make the following change to `packages/integration_test/ios/Classes/IntegrationTestPlugin.m`:

```
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
    [[IntegrationTestPlugin instance] setupChannels:registrar.messenger];
}
```

You might need to run `flutter clean` after this.

Now you're at the point where you can take screenshots!

As a bonus, this Python script will spin up a bunch of simulators / emulators for iOS and Android and drive the above integration test to take screenshots for all of them:

```py
import argparse
import asyncio
import logging
import os
import re


# The list of iOS simulators to run.
# This comes from inspecting `xcrun simctl list`
IOS_SIMULATORS = [
    "iPhone 8",
    "iPhone 8 Plus",
    "iPhone 13 Pro Max",
    "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)",
    "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
]

ANDROID_EMULATORS = [
    "Nexus_7_API_32",
    "Nexus_10_API_32",
    "Pixel_5_API_32",
]


LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
LOG.addHandler(ch)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--clear-screenshots", action="store_true", help="Delete all existing screenshots")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


class cd:
    """Context manager for changing the current working directory"""
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = os.path.expanduser(newPath)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)


async def run_command(command):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    if stderr:
        LOG.debug(f"stderr of command {command}: {stderr}")
    return stdout.decode("utf-8")


async def get_uuids_of_ios_simulators(simulators):
    command_output = await run_command(["xcrun", "simctl", "list"])

    out = {}
    for s in simulators:
        for line in command_output.splitlines():
            r = "    " + re.escape(s) + r" \((.*)\) \(.*"
            m = re.match(r, line)
            if m is not None:
                out[s] = m[1]

    return out


async def start_ios_simulators(uuids_of_ios_simulators):
    async def start_ios_simulator(uuid):
        await run_command(["xcrun", "simctl", "boot", uuid])

    await asyncio.gather(
        *[start_ios_simulator(uuid) for uuid in uuids_of_ios_simulators.values()]
    )


async def start_android_emulators(android_emulator_names):
    async def start_android_emulator(name):
        await run_command(["flutter", "emulators", "--launch", name])

    await asyncio.gather(
        *[start_android_emulator(name) for name in android_emulator_names]
    )


async def get_all_device_ids():
    raw = await run_command(["flutter", "devices"])
    out = []
    for line in raw.splitlines():
        if "•" not in line:
            continue
        if "Daniel" in line:
            continue
        if "Chrome" in line:
            continue
        device_id = line.split("•")[1].lstrip().rstrip()
        out.append(device_id)

    return out


async def run_tests(device_ids):
    async def run_test(device_id):
        LOG.info(f"Started testing for {device_id}")
        await run_command(
            [
                "flutter",
                "drive",
                "--driver=test_driver/integration_driver.dart",
                "--target=integration_test/screenshot_test.dart",
                "-d",
                device_id,
            ]
        )
        LOG.info(f"Finished testing for {device_id}")

    for device_id in device_ids:
        await run_test(device_id)

    # await asyncio.gather(*[run_test(device_id) for device_id in device_ids])


async def main():
    args = parse_args()

    # chdir to location of python file.
    abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
    os.chdir(dname)

    if args.debug:
        LOG.setLevel("DEBUG")
    else:
        LOG.setLevel("INFO")

    if args.clear_screenshots:
        await run_command(["rm", "ios/en-AU/*"])
        await run_command(["rm", "android/en-AU/*"])
        LOG.info("Cleared existing screenshots")

    uuids_of_ios_simulators = await get_uuids_of_ios_simulators(IOS_SIMULATORS)
    LOG.info(f"iOS simulatior name to UUID: {uuids_of_ios_simulators}")

    LOG.info("Launching iOS simulators")
    await start_ios_simulators(uuids_of_ios_simulators)
    LOG.info("Launched iOS simulators")

    LOG.info("Launching Android emulators")
    await start_android_emulators(ANDROID_EMULATORS)
    LOG.info("Launched Android emulators")

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    device_ids = await get_all_device_ids()
    LOG.debug(f"Device IDs: {device_ids}")

    LOG.info("Running tests")
    await run_tests(device_ids)
    LOG.info("Ran tests")

    LOG.info("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Note, if you try to take multiple screenshots on Android with this approach, you'll have a bad time. Check out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92381. The fix is still en route.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is impossible. At least for now. Flutter UI is rendered as a game would render which is much deeper than regular iOs UI. Moreover, flutter has its own gestures framework - thus you won't be able to correctly translate iOs gestures to flutter gestures(well you will be able but it will take too much effort). Also, native iOs UI testing framework(Xcode UI tests) is not supporting flutter and, I think, it will never will.

What you can do is look into flutter integration testing [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests) and [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction). Because they are flutter native - you will be able to address UI via various different ways(by Keys, class name, widget properties, etc.). You will be able to interact with that UI also.

Regarding screenshots - officially they are not supported [yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51890) but there are [other ways](https://dev.to/mjablecnik/take-screenshot-during-flutter-integration-tests-435k) basically what you need to do is:

```
//1. Replace your test_driver/integration_test.dart by this code(or similar by approach):
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test_driver_extended.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    await integrationDriver(
      onScreenshot: (String screenshotName, List<int> screenshotBytes) async {
        final File image = await File('screenshots/$screenshotName.png').create(recursive: true);
        image.writeAsBytesSync(screenshotBytes);
        return true;
      },
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error occured: $e');
  }
}


//2. Go into your integration_test/your_test_file.dart and add:
final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding();
IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

//3. And add this to your test:
await binding.takeScreenshot('some_screeshot_name_placeholder');
//If you run your tests on Android device, you must also add //convertFlutterSurfaceToImage() function before takeScreenshot() because //there must be converted a Flutter surface into image like this:
await binding.convertFlutterSurfaceToImage();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
await binding.takeScreenshot('some_screeshot_name_placeholder');
//For iOS or web you don't need this convert function.
```

The code is not mine, it is from the link above, when I was trying to implement it some time ago way before that article - it was not working - maybe now it is - you have to try.

You can also look into golden testing for flutter [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/matchesGoldenFile.html) or [here](https://appunite.com/blog/golden-testing-with-flutter) or just google it). There is even a library for that [here](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit).

Regarding taking screenshots via Fastlane - maybe it is possible while combining the approaches above with Fastlane scrips - I am not sure because it is quite unusual procedure, but you can try.